# Different behavior of ShowDialog() method if application run from VS2013 or run using double click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I have found several memory related differences when application is run using VS debugger and application started using double click on exe. 
In my application, I am opening a window as dialog programatically. window is displayed after 5 secs of application launched. 2 different behaviors are observed when application is in background and window is displayed. They are as followed.
1. when application is launched in VS debugger, new window (opened using showdialog()) comes in foreground.
2. When application is launched from exe, application icon in taskbar blinks, but window does not come in foreground.


I want to know how VS debugger affects application execution.? Is there other behavior as well which can be seen in different ways just like above case.
Below is my what I am doing. I have taken Timer and Dispatcher just to open new window without any user interaction.
**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private Dispatcher dispatcher = null;

void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(4000);
     timer.Elapsed += timer_elapsed;
     timer.Start();
}

private void timer_elapsed(X, X)
{
    dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new NoArgCallback(OpenWindow));
}

private void OpenWindow()
{
    Window2 w2 = new Window2(); // This is another window class
    w2.Owner = this;
    w2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Run Above code once in VS debugger and once using .exe and observe the behavior staying application in background. Actually I am showing new window as dialog on getting http response.

Comment: Please add some code and explain more in details what kind of dialog are you deal with

Comment: Do you hold any keys down? If you have keys pressed when an application starts it will not be able to take focus as another application will have captured the focus.

Comment: You can in general not steal the foreground away from another process.  The rules are convoluted, time does play a factor.  A new process of course always steals the foreground but it must do so in a timely manner.   And the debugger has an affect since it by design does a lot of foreground window swapping.  The basic Golden Rule is that a dialog must *always* have an owner window.  If it doesn't then the odds for foreground trouble greatly increase.  Not just when it is created but also when it is closed and there's no other window left to activate.

Comment: @Glen: I don't hold any keys down.

Comment: @HansPassant: You got my problem. But I have set owner and all that, but the actual outcome of same code is difference and it is as mentioned above.